# pvc windows constantly wet ...door handles dripping wet inside of premises

Tags: windows

I had windows fitted 6 years ago and still to this time  for ever wipe up puddles of water off all doors and windows ..plus its always draughty iv had insulation in walls roof and attic but its a no go its still cold u can feel wind blowing in in places on windows and doors I have had the company up and they say its natural so I have put tape on windows and around doors to see if that makes a difference to draught it did help ..water all I can do is put rags down or leave windows open 24/7 which is not  good

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live? Almost sounds like a cold and wet place like Alaska or Canada.

On the draftiness: Sounds like the windows are poor quality or they were installed incorrectly. A good window that's installed right should be airtight. You can caulk around the edges where the window meets the drywall, and that should stop air leaks between the window and the surrounding wall. If air is coming in between the frame and the sliding sash, you can buy and apply stick-on compressible weatherstripping gaskets that will seal when the window is closed. That should help. Even ancient single pane wood windows with zero weatherstripping are often measurably improved by this change.

On the moisture: getting condensation on the interior of your windows is a sign that the windows are poor insulators (R-3/U-0.33 or worse) and you have a lot of interior humidity. Because the windows are poor insulators, they're cold. When moist air hits a cold smooth surface, it condenses and turns into liquid water. To improve this state of affairs without replacing your windows with much more expensive higher quality triple-pane windows that do a much better job of controlling interior condensation, you can run a dehumidifier in winter, or you can install Low-E storm windows outside of the windows, or you can build **airtight** interior insulating shutters made out of foam board that completely cover the windows at night. But they would have to be airtight, sealed against the windows with gaskets. Otherwise moist air would get right past them and continue to condense on the windows.

Good luck.

Comment: Draftiness doesn't necessarily occur due to poor window installation. When you talk about the temp difference at the pane verses the interior, this creates convection currents where the warm air inside cools against the window, in addition to depositing moisture once it becomes saturated, it drops because it is now cooler. That air is replaced with other warm air which of course does the same thing. This will create a draft on an airtight window if it's an inefficient window. I've got 3-pane argon filled and you can still feel the slightest air movement right against the pane, not edges.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and this phenomenon gets worse the worse your windows are (i.e. the colder the interior glass pane is). But this results in interior air being cooled, not the infiltration of cold outside air. The air currents this will cause are nothing compared to the impact of frigid outside air streaming in.